# Python ~ Getting first few numbers from left to right

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am currently writing a programme with two variables in random and need to be calculated in an equation and want to fetch first three numbers and converting it to a percentage, the following is what I want the programme to reply

```
formular = (((((3*m-2*h)*g*c*b)/3*m)*o)/lvl)/100
print formular
#g and lvl are the random variables
```

the following is what I want it to output from the formular.

```
6920.157 to 69.2
3561.356 to 35.6
182435.24 to 18.2
```

Is there an inbuild function which allows that or what can I do?
Thank you for reading this and understanding my bad English (sorry for that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your output is a. And you can do this:

```
>>> a = 6920.157
>>> float(str(a)[:3])/10
69.2
```

Comment: This will fail with `a = 0.14222222222222222` Better use:  `float("%s.%s" % (str(a)[:2], str(a)[2:3])`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def convert(num):
    while num > 100:
        num /= 10.0;
    return "%.1f" % num
```

Output:

```
print(convert(6920.157))  # Prints 69.2
print(convert(3561.356))  # Prints 35.6
print(convert(182435.24)) # Prints 18.2
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, when I try this function with decimals, it returned ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '6920.15', how would you as well tell python that the "." is a decimal point?

Answer (score 0):

There's no inbuilt function, but it's easy to string something together with a couple of operations.

First is to reduce your number to 2 significant digits. You can get the number of significant digits with the `log` function, then use exponentiation to get the magnitude. Finish it off with a `round` to get one decimal after the integer.

```
digits = int(math.log(formular, 10)) + 1
two_digits = formular / (10 ** (digits - 2))
print round(two_digits, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tried it but it said formular is not defined. Do I have to import formular or is that just a variable?

Comment: @rcw it was just a variable, which I took directly from your question.

Comment: @MarkRandom Oh right, I used a new document... sorry